# VBA Excel - Summing a range of cells based on result in a different range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am attempting create a forecasting function in excel using based on a set of preregistered historical data. I am new to VBA and I am unable to make this function.

I have three Ranges:

- Range 1 lists every day in a year. All cells are formatted in the form of "date".
- Range 2 on a different sheet named "C" also lists every day in a year. All cells are formatted in the form of "date".
- Range 3 on sheet "C" contains the dollar value actualized in the specific date of the year mentioned in Range 2.

#### Requirement:

The function should take 3 different variables which are the three different ranges. The Function should first "`LOOKUP`" the month and year of the selected cell and match it with the month of and (year -1) of the cells in Range two.

Accordingly, The cells in Range 3 on the same row in which the "`LOOKUP`" matches with Range 2 should sum up and then divide by the count of cells counted.

So far I have been able to create a function named `MNAME`.

```vb
Function MNAME(x As Variant) As String
  Dim CurrentMonth As Date
  CurrentMonth = x
  MNAME = MonthName(Month(CurrentMonth), True)
End Function
```

But I am failing to nest the lookups and sum up the values.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this with VBA? Looking at you requirement seems it is possible to do this using the default functions provided in excel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need VBA.

**Read Up** on the `SUMPRODUCT()` function - [Here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) is a good explanation

to summarise your problem you want to find out:

1. if the year of the cells in `Range2` is the same as `YEAR(reference_cell)-1`

   ```
   --> IF(YEAR(reference_cell)-1=YEAR(Range2))
   ```
2. if the month of the cells in `Range2` is the same as `MONTH(reference_cell)`

   ```
   --> IF(MONTH(reference_cell)=MONTH(Range2))
   ```
3. where 1. IS `TRUE` and 2. IS `TRUE`, sum corresponding cells in `Range3`

   ```
   --> =SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(reference_cell)-1=YEAR(Range2))*--(MONTH(reference_cell)=MONTH(Range2))*Range3)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your support. The equation is not working with the `IF` statement. I removed the if but ended up with `#VALUE!`.

Comment: Sorry, I must have copied the wrong one. I have changed it now. notice the `--` it changes "True/False" into "1/0",which can then be multiplied with the value. Remember to name your ranges.

Comment: Great!! It seems to work, however if I'm selecting a full column, excel is returning `#VALUE` because my data has headers. Is there a possible solution for that?

Comment: I've set it into tables and it worked. Perfect & thank you :)